# Highlight brackets when caret be after bracket

Tags: emeditor

now, the  pair brackets be highlighted only when caret be before  bracket,
it will be good to highlight when caret be after bracket  , like vscode/jetbrains IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmEditor `v22.0.902 or later` will allow brackets highlighted even when the cursor is after the bracket.

Comment: Good Job! thank you very much !  emeditor is more and more powerful !